# How to style boostrap select

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, drop-down-menu

My app uses [bootstrap-select](https://silviomoreto.github.io/bootstrap-select/examples/)  for dropdowns. But the results look very different and undesirable.

[image]

HTML:

```
<div class="form-group">
    <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Enter your name">
    <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Enter your address">
    <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Enter your contact info">
    <select class="selectpicker form-control">
        <option selected="selected">Select one</option>
        <option value="1">1</option>
        <option value="2">2</option>
        <option value="3">3</option>
    </select>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.form {
    max-width: 330px;
    padding: 15px;
    padding-top: 120px;
    margin: 0 auto;
}
.form .form-heading {
    margin-bottom: 20px;
    text-align: center;
}
.form .form-control {
    position: relative;
    font-size: 16px;
    height: auto;
    padding: 10px;
    -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
    -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}
.form .form-control:focus {
    z-index: 2;
}
.form input[type="text"] {
    margin-bottom: -1px;
    border-radius: 0;
}
```

What is the best way to fix this? Should I add CSS for bootstrap-select?

Comment: There are some styling options available as described https://silviomoreto.github.io/bootstrap-select/examples/#styling, but the tricky issue is that `bootstrap-select` generates new HTML and hides the original `select[class=form-control]` element, so you'd need custom CSS targeting the generated element.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Heres a basic example of what it looks like you are trying to do. If you review the **bootstrap-select** stylesheet or inspect the element in the browser you'll be able to see what you need to target as **bootstrap-select** adds a dropdown button to the `select` field.

**Working Example:**

```js
$('.selectpicker').selectpicker();
```

```css
.form {
  max-width: 330px;
  padding: 15px;
  margin: 120px auto 0;
}
.form .form-control {
  font-size: 16px;
  padding: 10px;
  height: auto;
  border-radius: 0;
  margin: 0;
}
.form .bootstrap-select {
  padding: 0;
  height: auto;
}
.form .dropdown-toggle {
  border-radius: 0;
  padding: 10px;
}
.form .dropdown-menu {
  border-radius: 0;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-select/1.10.0/css/bootstrap-select.min.css">
<div class="container">

  <div class="form">

    <div class="form-group">
      <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Enter your name">
      <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Enter your address">
      <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Enter your contact info">
      <select class="selectpicker form-control">
        <option selected="selected">Select one</option>
        <option value="1">1</option>
        <option value="2">2</option>
        <option value="3">3</option>
      </select>
    </div>

  </div>
</div>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-select/1.10.0/js/bootstrap-select.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 1):

I tested this and it works fine for me:

http://codepen.io/calebanth/pen/grKzkB

Did you remember to use all the dependencies? You need:

```
jQuery
bootstrap.js
bootstrap.css
```

Plus

```
bootstrap-select.css
bootstrap-select.js
```

Comment: Yep I have all of them

Comment: @jebmarcus There must be something else in your code that we can't see that's causing the issue then. Can you post your entire code, preferably in something like CodePen or JSFiddle?

Comment: I went in to the codepen you created and added a "<div class="form">" right before "<div class="form-group">", if you try that you will see the error

Comment: @jebmarcus I just updated the CodePen and changed `class="form-group"` to `class="form"` and it still looks fine, I can't get it to match the image you originally posted.